# calculate date from 2 field oracle

Tags: oracle

This is my Oracle query :

```
SELECT to_char(EVALUATION_DATE2, 'YYYY-MM-DD')DATE_EVAL,EVALUATION_DAY2 FROM RELATION_MASTER
```

[image]

I want to count a date with variable from another field like a picture and the result show in Result_Date Field.

> Result_date = DATE_EVAL + EVALUATION_DAY2

Answer (score 0):

If `DATE_EVAL`'s datatype is `DATE`, then

```
select date_eval + evaluation_day2 as result_date ...
```

If it is a string (some of `CHAR` datatypes), then

```
select to_date(date_eval, 'yyyy-mm-dd') + evaluation_day2 as result_date ...
```

Comment: Kamil fixed wrong function call (should be to_date, while I wrote (by mistake) to_char). Nonetheless, you're welcome.